# Java type promotion with "expressions"

Tags: java, types, promotions

Can the variable below (called b) be called an expression, if it is the only thing located to right of the equals sign?

```
// This code fragment will not compile.
// c is a char, and b is a byte.

c = b;
```

The reason why I ask this question is because of the topic of type promotion within expressions.  I understand that Java promotes all bytes to ints.  Is that the only reason why this code fragment does not compile?  (Please note that I know about casts; that's not the point of this thread.  Thanks a lot.)

**Edit:**
Thanks a lot Jon and Peter.  Looking at this topic using a second example:

```
byte b = 1;
short s = 2;

s = b;  // OK
s = b*2;  // Not OK (compilation error)
```

Is it true that the following is happening?

(Line 3) Java converts the byte to short.
(Line 4) Java converts the expression b*2 to an int.

If this is correct, then it would seem that =b; and =b*2; are "expressions" that Java handles differently.  So, the =b; "expression" is not converted to an int, but widened to a short.  But the =b*2; expression is converted to an int, and not to a short, even though the target variable called s is a short.

**Edit 2:**
Also -

```
short s1, s2 = 2, s3 = 2;
s1 = s2*s3;  // Not OK (compilation error)
```

Even though all three variables are shorts, the s2*s3; expression is promoted to an int, and thus causes a compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the variable below (called b) be called an expression, if it is the only thing located to right of the equals sign?

Yes, absolutely.

> I understand that Java promotes all bytes to ints.

Well, in some cases. Not in *all* cases.

Fundamentally the code doesn't compile because there's no implicit conversion from `byte` to `char`. From [section 5.1.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) (widening primitive conversions):

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - `byte` to `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - ...

Note the lack of `char` in the list of target types for conversions from `byte`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
byte b = -1;
short s = b; // is ok as a byte can be promoted to an short.
int i = b; // is ok as a byte can be promoted to an int.
float f = b; // is ok as a byte can be promoted to an float, long or double.

char c = b; // won't compile
```

but

```
final byte b = 1;
char c = b; // compiles fine as the compiler can inline the value.
```

---

In this case

```
short s = b*2;  // Not OK (compilation error)
```

b * 2 is an `int` as `2` is an `int` value.  If `b` were final you would be able to do this was the compile can inline the value.

Comment: Is there any JLS for the last part? I also tried `final int b = 1; char c = b;` and it compiles, while `final long b = 1; char c = b;` doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I've edited my O.P. to discuss the second line in your example code; short s = b;

Comment: Re: short s = b*2.  If you have three shorts used in this line: s1 = s2*s3.  The s2*s3 expression is converted to an int!  I now realise that bytes, shorts and chars are converted to ints within expressions.  I also realise that a variable declaration including an initilizer such as short s = b is not treated by Java in this same way.  That's interesting. :)

Comment: @user2911290 At the byte code level boolean, byte, short, char, int, float all use the same amount of space on the stack, one 32-bit location.  These types use different amounts of memory in an array or object.